# How to 'inherit' from IDbConnection - just add one property (DatabaseType)

Tags: c#, inheritance, idbconnection

How do you inherit from `IDbConnection`?  I would like to add one property (`DatabaseType` like MS Access, SQL server, Paradox...).  From what I can tell `IDbConnection` is an interface and thus I believe they want me to implement all members in the entire interface inheritance chain. That seems like a lot of work. What is the best way to add one property to `IDbConnection`?

**Update**
What I am trying to do is this.  I have three methods that I use heavily: ExecuteReader, ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteNonQueryGetIdentity.  They are heavily used and have parameters (IDbConnection Conn, string SQLString, object[] SQLParams).  I thought the best way to add DatabaseType to these three methods and all my project methods was to 'override' IDbConnection so that I only have to update one line of code in my project.

I want to know DatabaseType because there are a few things I do differently when adding parameters and building the IDbCommand.  Specifically for DateTime.

E.g.:

```
public static System.Data.IDataReader ExecuteReader(System.Data.IDbConnection Conn, string SQL, object[] SQLParams)
// return IDataReader from connection, SQL string and Params. Params can be null. 
{
  using (var cmd = Conn.CreateCommand())
  {
    cmd.CommandText = SQL;
    AddParametersToCommand(cmd, SQLParams);   // add parameters to IDbCommand object if params not null
    return cmd.ExecuteReader();  
  }
}

private static readonly Regex regParameters = new Regex(@"@\w+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
public static void AddParametersToCommand(IDbCommand Cmd, object[] Parameters)
/* Creates and ads unique parameters to an IDbCommand object to the CommandText SQL string.
  * Tested types with SQL Update statement in MS Access/SQL Server: boolean, int, DateTime, text
  * Parameter names in CommandText must start with the '@' char and can be any unique word (letter or number).
  * E.g. calling code: cmd.CommandText = "Select * From SiteUser Where Site > @1 And User > @NewParam"
  * 
  * http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15542/IDbDataParameter-error-in-NET  re: some DateTime issues
*/
{
  if (Parameters != null && Parameters.Length > 0)
  {
    MatchCollection cmdParams = regParameters.Matches(Cmd.CommandText);
    var paramNames = new List<String>();
    foreach (var el in cmdParams)
    {
      if (!paramNames.Contains(el.ToString()))   // only add unique parameter names
        paramNames.Add(el.ToString());
    }
    IDbDataParameter dp;
    var dbType = GetDatabaseType(Cmd.Connection);
    for (int n = 0; n < Parameters.Length; n++)
    {
      var param = Parameters[n];
      dp = Cmd.CreateParameter();
      dp.ParameterName = paramNames[n];
      TypeCode myTypeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(param.GetType());
      if (myTypeCode == TypeCode.DateTime)     // this workaround is needed for MS Access and SQL Server
      {
        if (dbType == DatabaseType.Access)
        {
          dp.DbType = DbType.DateTime;         // set dates as DbType.DateTime for MS Access and Paradox
          dp.Value = param.ToString();         // Convert.ToDateTime(param).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));         
          //Note: MS access cannot store years before December 30, 1899. They will be stored for some other year.
          // for example. Jan 1 0001 will be stored as 2001.
        }
        else if (dbType == DatabaseType.MSSql)
        {
          dp.DbType = DbType.DateTime2;        // set dates as DbType.DateTime2 for SQL Server
          dp.Value = param.ToString();
        }
      }
      else
        dp.Value = param;
      Cmd.Parameters.Add(dp);
    } // for n
  } // if
}
```

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this?  Depending on why you want to, there may be different ways to do it.

Comment: Interfaces aren't inherited - they're implemented. What is it exactly that you're trying to do? If you just want a class that has everything in `IDbConnection` but with the `DatabaseType` you should go with Steve's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create new interface `MyDbConnection` with `DatabaseType` property, but none of existing `IDbConnection` implementations will implement your interface.

I think you should not care which implementation of `IDbConnection` you are using (MS Access, SQL server, Paradox etc). That's why we have this abstraction and [`DbProviderFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.aspx) classes, which totally abstract type of database we are working with.

*BTW* you can always check type of `IDbConnection` instance to see which implementation you are using (if you *really* need that). Another option for you (if you *really* need that property) - create decorator over `IDbConnection` instance:

```
public class MyDbConnection : IDbConnection
{
    private IDbConnection _connection;

    public MyDbConnection(IDbConnection connection)
    {
       _connection = connection;
    }

    // here goes your property
    public string DatabaseType { get; set; }

    public void Close()
    {
        _connection.Close();
    }

    public IDbTransaction BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel il)
    {
        return _connection.BeginTransaction(il);
    }

    // implement other IDbConnection members by delegating work to _connection
}
```

You can use this decorator everywhere as `IDbConnection`, but also your property will be available.

Comment: In the updated question details I explain why I need to know underlying Database type (not just Connection type) with regards to updating early DateTime fields in MS Access, SQL Server, Paradox etc.

Comment: @user610064 just interesting - your application uses dates before `1899`?

Comment: OK I admit only for elapsed time.  We have been using DateTime's to store elapsed time in some cases...  It was pretty handy at the time. Now converting MS Access to SQL Server...

Comment: @user610064 if you have problems with DateTime only, then just extract method which will create DbParameter, i.e. `AddParameter(command, name, object)`. And call that method from your ExecuteXXX methods.

Answer (score 0):

DbConnection implements the interface IDbConnection. You could just extend that (It must implement all of the interfaces methods)